# How to handle deletions of records from a database at file-level

Tags: database, algorithm, file-io

I'm developing a simple database system (don't want the overhead of using a stock database system even as simple as gdbm/bdb), and I'm trying to figure out what would be the most effective way of handling the deletion of records from inside the database file.

I've come up with two seemingly-naive solutions, one expensive in memory and the other expensive in disk space, and both seem expensive in terms of time.  The first one involves reading the entire database into memory, then rewriting it over the old database except for the record that needs deleted.  The second involves copying, record-by-record, from the old database file to a new database file (skipping over the record to be deleted), and then copying the new over the old.

Is there a better way?  How do existing database packages handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to just mark the section of the file as unused when a record is deleted, you could then add other records into that section of the file when a new entry is added. You could optionally have some sort of 'shrink' process that will follow one of the methods that you mentioned at a specified interval.

I'm pretty sure MySQL's innodb table type uses a method similar to this for managing files (although they don't offer a shrink method).

Comment: I thought of that, but it seemed unduly complex.

Answer (score 0):

Is your database implemented as a flat file ? i think that you can consider using [B+ tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B+_tree)
 as it will make it simpler as compared to the approaches you mentioned.

Comment: I'm afraid you might be conflating the question of how to remove a record from the logical structure of the database with how to actually commit that removal to disk.  My question is the latter.

But to answer your question: the index is structured as a tree (not a B+ tree), with the records themselves being inserted sequentially.